# How to get updates from a server using android app?

Tags: android, server

I basically just want to implement an app that uses the observer pattern: subject is supposed to notify the server that some of his/her attributes have changed, and observers need those updates so they can do something with them.

I don't need to store any information in a database, as long as there's an app running on a server that can store a few bytes and can notify observers what news subject has, I'm good.

What kind of cheap server can I use/hire to accomplish this and allowing many observers to connect to a subject?

Can subject's device act as a server for his observers?

Answer (score -2):

Well basically, if you need to store data of many users, or get some data by many users then you need a sharing point to be accessed by all of these lasts, so you need an external server, now coming to the server part, which one you need to use ?,

First of all you need to define your needs, if they're not so big (few mega bytes) you can use **Google Sheets API**, but if you need a strong back-end, you've got to use **Firebase** since some services are for free (you pay as you go), there's even live data, but if you want a customized running Services, then you need to code a web back-end, then you host it on a VPS or on a cloud or on a dedicated server. If you choose the last option then see these hosting providers:

https://www.digitalocean.com/

https://eu.alibabacloud.com/

https://www.ssdnodes.com/